# Posting an array into a php document

Tags: php, arrays, posting

I want to be able to post an array containing...

```
$food = array (
   'food_1' => 'ice cream ',
   'food_2' => 'pizza'
);

<input type="text" id="in_foods[]" value="<?=$food;?>" />
```

to another page but it does not seem to be working. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't post a non scalar data type in a single input field. You may use a list of checkboxes for this.

Comment: How you are accessing it in another page?

Comment: this all the code there is?

Comment: Use the multi-selected dropdown for post the multiple data with same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner solution will be to:

1- convert the array into a string using the implode function:

```
$foods = implode(',',$foods);
```

2- Place it in the input text field to be submitted:

```
<input type="text" id="foods" value="<?=$food;?>" />
```

3- On the other page convert the string back to an array:

```
$foods = explode(',',$_POST['foods'])
```

Try ;)

Answer (score 0):

As $food is an array.

```
<input type="text" id="in_foods[]" value="<? 
         if (isset($food)) { echo $food['food_1'].', '.$food['food_2']; } ?>" 
 />
```

If size of $food array is not defined then you can use implode function to make it as single string and can echo it.

Comment: What happens if `$food` has 3 elements? Or more?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just post a data structure like that. You should be getting a notice saying you're trying to convert an array to string.

Consider putting your array into a session instead. That way it stays as an array between calls.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['food'] = $food;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wan't to tick foods you like out of a predefined list of foods or something like this. In this case an `<input type="text">` field is not the right choice. Use `<input type="checkbox">` instead (or a `<select multiple>`).

```
$foodOptions = array('burger', 'vergtables', 'berries')

foreach($foodOptions as $foodOpt) {
    $checked = in_array($foodOpt, $foods)?' checked':null;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' , $foodOpt , '" name="in_foods[]"', $checked ,'><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```html
<?php
$food = array (
   'food_1' => 'ice cream ',
   'food_2' => 'pizza'
);
$food = implode(",", $food);
?>
<input type="text" id="in_foods[]" value="<?=$food;?>" />
```